# RStudio server hangs for 1 user only

Tags: linux, r, rstudio

I am running RStudio Server version 0.98.978 with R 3.0.2. on an Ubuntu 14 server. Yesterday I executed a command that caused the session to freeze. Since then, every time I try to load that user profile and that user profile only, the browser hangs. I generally get an error message saying the browser has become unresponsive (regardless of whether I use Chrome or IE ).

Simple commands like R.Version() take several minutes to complete. I have tried rebooting the server and killing all processes related to the RStudio account in question. So far nothing has resolved the problem. My searches have only brought up solutions to fix the problem on Windows. What else can I try to fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe try removing them and re-adding them `sudo deluser xyz` / `sudo adduser xyz`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to do a `ps -u user` where `user` is the user whose session is hanging in the browser, and kill the rsession related to it.

I had the same issue and was about to give up and delete my user when almost serendipitiously, I couldn't delete it due to an ongoing processes tied to my user. I did a `ps -u jp_smasher` where `jp_smasher` is my user name and found an offending `rsession`.

`[root]# ps -u jp_smasher
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
 39774 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 39776 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 39888 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 39889 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 39999 pts/0    00:02:24 R
 54230 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 54231 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 54372 ?        00:00:11 rsession
 54503 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 54504 ?        00:00:00 sftp-server
 69992 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 69993 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
[root]# kill 54372`

Killing the process doesn't solve the main problem (which could be some memory-hogging process etc), but it does resolve the symptom of the hanging browser.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and none of above solutions worked for me. I Tried following steps and problem solved:

1- Suspand all tasks:

```
`$ sudo rstudio-server force-suspend-all`
```

2- Stop RStudio server:

```
`$ sudo rstudio-server stop`
```

3- Delete .rstudio folder in /home/user/.rstudio:

```
`$ rm /home/user/.rstudio`
```

4- Start RStudio server:

```
`$ sudo rstudio-server start`
```

5- Open your browser and start using RStudio Server :)

Comment: in my case it says no such file or directory in step 3 what to do?

Comment: `$ rm /home/user/.rstudio` was enough for me. no need to restart the server and throw everyone  who might be working in parallel out.

Comment: @mohitji See answer by Matifou for Rstudio versions >= 1.3.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that the `~/.rstudio` folder is for versions of Rstudio < 1.3. For newer versions, you will want to look at `~/.local/share/rstudio/sessions` instead, and remove the folder within it instead.

See: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218730228-Resetting-a-user-s-state-on-RStudio-Server, which mentions *Older versions of (version 1.3 of RStudio Server Pro and earlier) used a non-configurable folder named .rstudio to store state*

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you have a huge .Rdata file under your home directory so Rstudio tries to reload it everytime you restart your session. Delete that file and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried deleting the only .Rdata file under that directory, but am still having the same problem. Does Rstudio stash hidden or temporary files in other places? I also want to say that the file was only 35mb or so, which is in line with other files that I can load quite easily.

Comment: We had a similar issue as you described before and was caused by huge size of hidden session files rstudio tried to recover everytime when a user signed on. It then ate all the memory on the machine and make the session unresponsive. I would suggest you check 1) is the home directory default start directory for rstudio? 2) if there are other r related hidden files under the start directory?

Comment: In this case I was not able to resolve the problem. I found a number of hidden files, but I was unable to determine whether or not deleting those files would impact other users on the server.  I'll continue to investigate; in the interim, I'll share what not to do. I went in to the hidden directory username/suspended-session and deleted the environment and environment-vars files. Not only did this not solve the problem, it made it worse.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to that you have processed larger files. Just kill the particular r session. That will suffice.
Command: ps -u 
find out the rsession and kill it.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem - Rstudio-server hanging 1 person only. But I could not solve it with above methods. I think it is a network problem so I couldn't receive any response from <~~~~~~.cache.js> calling. In this case, you can find out <~~~~~~~~~.cache.js> no response with pushing  key before you click log-in button.

Anyway, here is my way.

1. Reset your Network with following orders

   - you can insert these into cmd terminal as an admin mode.

netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset

2. Reboot
3. The IP information may be erased.
   So if you're using fixed IP address, fill the blanks with as-is IP address.

That's all.

Since there could be a network issue when you cannot login into Rstudio server,
you may take this way to recover the connection.